# WeChat and QQ Profile URLs

Tags: url-scheme, wechat, icq

Snapchat has a profile URL https://www.snapchat.com/add/username

QQ and WeChat used to have URL schemes:

```
http://weixin.qq.com/r/WeChatIDgoeshere

icq:message?uin=ICQIDgoeshere
```

None of them work - they either just open the app or open the google play app store - not the profile or messaging activity windows - on Android.

What are the QQ and WeChat URL schemes or URL to profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL should be 
     https://icq.com/people/ICQIDgoeshere

I don't think WeChat has one yet.